# Condition on invertible function implies derivative is linear isomorphism

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F$ be a differentiable function with differentiable inverse from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to show that the derivative of $F$ at any point is a linear isomorphism.

I think that  by definition $DF$ is linear, so it suffices to prove injectivity. Here I hit a snag; this seems to be a converse of the inverse function theorem, but I'm not sure where to go. One thought was to use the Mean Value Inequality, but I don't see how to apply it if all that I know is that the derivative has determinant 0 at a point.

What can I say about $F$ locally if the determinant of $DF$ at a point is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the Chain Rule to $$I=F\circ F^{-1}. $$

Comment: I see! So, doing this gives me $I(x) = DF(F^{-1}) \circ DF^{-1}(x)$ and vice versa, giving that they both have nonzero determinant, (or just that they are both invertible by specifying inverse)?

Comment: One side is enough, since we are dealing with matrices (no need for "viceversa").